# Need a generic solution to remove any special encoding from all UI input controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, encoding, character-encoding

I trying to find a generic solution for my problem that I faced few days ago. Basically, 
apart from typing in values in our winforms UI, the user tries to paste data from some reports (in html and excel) and tries to search for the information.

Apparently, this doesnt work since our WCF service doesnt understand the encoding format of the string and returns no records. This is surprising for the user since they could get results when they type the same string and search for it. 
problem discussed here : [String Encoding Issue - Need to convert 'Western European to Ascii'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840027/string-encoding-issue-need-to-convert-western-european-to-ascii)

But, I know this could occur in any UI screens of our app and hence need to know what could be a generic and the one place to implement the solution. Is it possible to make all controls in a form to remove any encoding ? or may be any way to ensure services can ignore any special encoding in strings ? or there is no other alternative other than to reformat the text from every single input text box in the UI ?

Thanks.

Comment: In WPF have IValueConverter.  I would use a converter with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bc2hwcb.aspx in WPF.

Comment: Sorry this is winforms. Btw, your link takes to StreamReader !

Comment: Exactly did you not notice the second parameter? bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks !  That is not an option on TextReader.  That link has several examples of how to apply the encoding to text.

Comment: @Blam - Well, the question is actually different. The question is what could be the best way to apply encoding techniques generically for all controls in a UI. Not sure why did you even downvoted the question, when your answer is so irrelvant.

Answer (score 1):

Forms are container controls which have trees of containers and subcontainers. You could walk down the tree of controls until you find labels/textboxes that you want to change the encoding for on form load.

You could also implement this as a behavior for your WCF service (so that it automatically handles the encoding).

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to 'change the encoding or set default encoding' for controls ?

Comment: @Mani Even if you set a default how would you control that all input would be the same encoding?

Comment: @Blam - Thats right, thats exactly the point of discussion. I am not sure if there is a bullet proof solution to this problem but would like to know if there is one or best ways to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better create your custom TextBoxes. Inherit from TextBox class and override it's Text property getter and call your reformatting method there.

It would not be so difficult to search for all textboxes in your solution and replace them whith your new custom TextBox.